# Can I put array variable in nested for loop?

Tags: ruby

Below is my ruby code..

```
a = Array.new(10)

(0..10).each do |i|
  a[i] = 0
end

(1..5).each do |t|
  a[t] = gets.chomp
end

(0..10).each do |i|
  (1..a[i]).each do |j|
    puts i
  end
end
```

It seems something wrong with  1..a[i], why?

Comment: `(10)` is meaningless in your `a = Array.new(10)` for two reasons: (i) you are rewriting all elements to be `0`, (ii) you are even adding the eleventh element (to be `0`), so even setting the number of elements to `10` does not have meaning.

Comment: How is your code wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets.chomp` returns a string, but you need an integer to generate a range.

Just change the line with the `gets.chomp` to:

```
a[t] = gets.to_i
```